# Change `\overline` command with `\uc`

Tags: macros

I'm trying to change `\overline` command with `\uc` completely. But pdflatex is giving error below:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded
```

The code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\newcommand{\uc}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1mu#1\mkern-0.3mu}\mkern 0mu}
\let\overline\uc
\renewcommand*{\uc}[1]{\overline[#1]}

\begin{document}
\noindent X $\uc{X}$ X\\
Y $\uc{Y}$ Y
\end{document}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not fully certain of your goal, but you logic is self referential in that `\overline` invokes `\uc` and vice versa.  You have thus set up an infinite loop.  The standard way of dealing with such situations is to first save a copy of the existing macro, in this case `\let\svoverline\overline`.  Then, define `\uc` and/or redefine `\overline` in terms of the saved verion.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\let\svoverline\overline
\newcommand{\uc}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\svoverline{\mkern-1mu#1\mkern-0.3mu}\mkern 0mu}
\let\overline\uc
%\renewcommand*{\uc}[1]{\svoverline[#1]}

\begin{document}
\noindent X $\uc{X}$ X\\
Y $\uc{Y}$ Y
\end{document}
```

Comment: The \overline is very long so i'm trying to change the command _completely_. It fits because i need only a few letters with \overline. But i'm not sure i'm using the _proper_ code.

Comment: @mert  Without knowing visually what you are trying to achieve, it is hard for me to say more.  But when one wants to redefine a macro in terms of its former self, one has to express it in terms of a *copy* of its former self, in order to avoid the infinite loop.  Best wishes... you can always ask a different question to clarify a point.